# F test and categorical variables

Tags: regression, stata, robust, f-test

I am trying to compute a regression.

I have a continuous dependent variable (investment in millions of dollars)
One continuous independent variables
Five dichotomous indicators (1 / 0)
Four interactions.
Robust standard errors are being used.

N=569.

Is there any particular reason why the F-Test is not being worked out in Stata?

Stata help says:

> Your estimation results show an F or chi2 model statistic reported to
>   be missing.  Stata has done that so as to not be misleading, not
>   because there is something necessarily wrong with your model

The problem seems to be related to the interactive dummy variables, because when I remove them the F test is calculated.

The regression output is the following

```
Linear regression                                        Number of obs =  580
                                                         F(  9,   569) =  .
                                                         Prob > F      =  .
                                                         R-squared     =  0.2336
                                                         Root MSE      =  1.2608


                                          Robust
lninv                         Coef.       Std. Err.  t      P>t    [95% Conf. Interval]

age                           0.1392668   0.0363307  3.83   0.000    .0679081  0.2106255
1.idicatorone                 0.4070426   0.2380546  1.71   0.088   -.0605304  0.8746155
1.indicatortwo                1.085003    0.1235029  8.79   0.000    .8424262  1.327581
1.indicatorthree              -0.4390229  0.1781991  -2.46  0.014   -.7890312 -0.0890145
1.fincrisis                   0.4526393   0.1376538  3.29   0.001    .1822677  0.7230108
1.bubble                      1.657902    0.1088199  15.24  0.000    1.444165  1.87164
indicatorone#indicatortwo                                                     
    1 1                       0.0810565   0.2113363  0.38   0.701   -.3340379  0.496151
 bubble#indicatorthree                                                        
    1 1                       -0.8225963  0.2688304  -3.06  0.002   -1.350617 -0.2945752
fincrisis#indicatorthree                                                      
    1 1                       -0.1068982  0.2141135  -0.5   0.618   -.5274474  0.313651
 indicatorthree#c.age                                                         
1                             -0.0103719  0.0450553  -0.23  0.818   -.0988669  0.0781231
 _cons                        0.0378515   0.1878819  0.2    0.840   -.3311753  0.4068783
```

Comment: What is the exact command that resulted in that message?

Comment: When I use the regress command, the F test does not show. I click on it, since its in blue, and it leads me to help file which shows that message.

Comment: Can you paste the entire regression output in your question?

Comment: Done, I'm not sure how to get it in a more presentable format, but that's basically it.

Comment: Has anything been dropped from this regression due to perfect collinearity? 9+569 do not add up to 580, and you have 10 predictors rather than 9 used for the F-statistic.

Comment: As far as I know there are no issues with collinearity.

Comment: @StasK It turned out this happens because I am using robust standard errors. Any guidance on reporting same would be appreciated.